# delete a row where the order is wrong within a group

Tags: r

I have a data with about 1000 groups each group is ordered from 1-100(can be any number within 100).
As I was looking through the data. I found that some groups had bad orders, i.e., it would order to 100 then suddenly a 24 would show up.
How can I delete all of these error data

[image]

As you can see from the picture above(before -> after), I would like to find all rows that don't follow the order within the group and just delete it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lag` will compute the difference between the current value and the previous value, `diff` will be used to select only positive difference i.e. the current value is greater than the previous value. min is used as lag give the first value `NA`. I keep the helper column `diff` to check, but you can deselect  using `%>% select(-diff)`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% group_by(gruop) %>% mutate(diff = order-lag(order)) %>% 
         filter(diff >= 0 | order==min(order))

   # A tibble: 8 x 3
   # Groups:   gruop [2]
   gruop order diff
    <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1    NA
 2     1     3     2
 3     1     5     2
 4     1    10     5
 5     2     1    NA
 6     2     4     3
 7     2     4     0
 8     2     8     4
```

## Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
              gruop order
              1 1
              1 3
              1 5
              1 10
              1 2
              2 1
              2 4
              2 4
              2 8
              2 3
               ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the order increments is not by 1 but random within 1~100

Comment: bustag %>% group_by(dispatch) %>% mutate(diff = order-lag(stnorder)) %>% 
  filter(order==min(stnorder))  I ran the code like this since there are repeated numbers. but the error non-numeric argument to binary operator. pops up

Comment: even checked the columns for if they are numeric. Still the non-numeric arguemnt to binary operator comes up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176785/discussion-between-signalstone-and-a-suliman).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `order` column increments by 1 every time we can use `ave` where we remove those rows which do not have difference of 1 with the previous row by `group`.

```
df[!ave(df$order, df$group, FUN = function(x) c(1, diff(x))) != 1, ]

#  group order
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     1     3
#4     1     4
#6     2     1
#7     2     2
#8     2     3
#9     2     4
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated example, we can just change the comparison

```
df[ave(df$order, df$group, FUN = function(x) c(1, diff(x))) >= 0, ]
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the order increments is not by 1 but random within 1~100.

Comment: @signalstone updated the answer according to the new example.

Answer (score 1):

Playing with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, diffo := c(1, diff(order)), group][diffo == 1, .(group, order)]
   group order
1:     1     1
2:     1     2
3:     1     3
4:     1     4
5:     2     1
6:     2     2
7:     2     3
8:     2     4
```

Where `df1` is:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  group = rep(1:2, each = 5),
  order = c(1:4, 2, 1:4, 3)
)
```

**EDIT**

If you only need increasing order, and not steps of one then you can do:

```
df3 <- transform(df1, order = c(1,3,5,10,2,1,4,7,9,3))
setDT(df3)[, diffo := c(1, diff(order)), group][diffo >= 1, .(group, order)]
   group order
1:     1     1
2:     1     3
3:     1     5
4:     1    10
5:     2     1
6:     2     4
7:     2     7
8:     2     9
```